# How to delete all rows from all tables without without deleting (drop) database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the command:

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

But I have to reopen my app for the above code to work.
Is that another way that I can do it without saying every table name or deleting my database?

Comment: Just use DELETE, without any WHERE clause. All records will be removed from the table, not the table itself.

Comment: yeah but imagine a mess of code with it I have to write a delete for each table on my database what if I create a new one and I forget to add. CodeBulls show me how to get all tables names that what I was looking for

Comment: I don't know why this question get a down vote I think is pretty clear what I want, Now I have to delete the question so I don't lose points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dropping the table, call onCreate too.

```
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName");
onCreate(database);
```

Comment: Do I have to say every table name? Because things can get complicated when I have a lot of tables with foreign key.

Comment: Probably you might want to fetch all your tables from sqlite_master - This table is an index of all tables defined.